# Set orientation in chromedriver mobile emulation mode

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

In a python selenium project I am trying to set orientation of an emulated mobile device to landscape where the default seems to be portrait. Does the capability exist to specify it, something like below?

`        mobile_emulation = {
"deviceName": "Samsung Galaxy S8+",
"orientation": "landscape"
}

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`
```

Or must I specify and flip the width and height using something like:

`"deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 }`

I read the documentation at https://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation and google searched, but couldn't find anything up to date or relevant other than needing to specify WxH